# Request user to identify file location and auto-extract variable name from file location in R

Tags: r, title

I am EXTREMELY new to R, and programming in general, so thank you for your patience.

I am trying to write a script which reads values from a .txt file and after some manipulation plots the results. I have two questions which are somewhat coupled.

First, is there a function which asks the user to identify the location of a file? i.e. User runs script. Script opens up file navigation prompt and requests user to navigate to and select relevant file.

Currently, I have to manually identify the file and location in R. e.g.

> spectra.raw <- read.table("C:\Users\...\file1.txt", row.names=NULL, header = TRUE)

I'd rather have the user identify the file location each time the script is run. This will be used by non-tech people, and I don't trust them to copy/paste file locations into R.

The second question I've been struggling with is, is it possible to create a variable name based off the file selected? For example, if the user selects "file1.txt" I'd like R to assign the output of read.table() to a variable named "file1.raw" much like the above "spectra.raw"

If it helps, all the file names will have the exact same number of characters, so if it's possible to select the last say 5 characters from the file location, that would work.

Thank you very much, and please excuse my ignorance.

Answer (score 4):

1. See `file.choose`. Though I believe it behaves slightly differently on different platforms, so beware of that.
2. See `assign`, i.e. `assign("fileName",value)`. You'll want to parse the file path that `file.choose` spits back using string manipulation functions like `substr` or `strsplit`.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
file.choose
```

I think it can do what you want.

For example,

```
myfile <- file.choose()
Enter file name: adataset.Rdata
load(myfile)
```

`myfile` contains the name of the file so you don't have to do anything special.